# Adding an A record where the host name has a forward slash

Tags: domain-name-system

I want to add an A record `www.mydomain.com/customer` and point it to say `123.456.789.001` where www.mydomain.com is my domain.

When i tried to enter the value i am getting an **invalid host name** error and on doing a little check i found that `"/"` is not allowed.

But my domain reseller service wants me to add an A record with the host name as www.mydomain.com/customer How do i manage it?

Is it even possible to add an A record which has a `/` in it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

DNS is not HTTP.  It knows nothing about URLs.  It *only* deals with domain names.

Therefore, adding an A or CNAME record that refers to a *portion* of your domain won't be possible.  A record applies to the whole domain.  If `/customer` is intended to be on a whole other server, then consider a subdomain like `customer.mydomain.com`.   (Any DNS host that's worth the money you pay them will let you add records for subdomains besides "www".)

Comment: My DNS host allows me to add subdomains and i have added the customer.mydomain.com pointing to the IP address i was given but now I get a server not found error. I understand that it is normal for the DNS propagation to take some time.. how long do you suppose it will take for it to resolve? Is there any other way to find out if the settings worked?